# Export HTML divs in one PDF file

Tags: php, pdf, html, pdf-generation

I have the following div that contain other divs that are shown or hide based on inputs buttons for each of them:

```
<div class="insightsgraphs">
    <div id="dailyNewLikes"><img src="css/images/loading.gif"></div>
    <div id="dailyNewLikes2"><img src="css/images/loading.gif"></div>
    <div id="dailyUnlikes"><img src="css/images/loading.gif"></div>
    <div id="dailyUnlikes2"><img src="css/images/loading.gif"></div>
    <div id="dailyPageViews"><img src="css/images/loading.gif"></div>
    <div id="dailyPageViews2"><img src="css/images/loading.gif"></div>
    <div id="dailyPostsImpressions"><img src="css/images/loading.gif"></div>
    <div id="dailyPostsImpressions2"><img src="css/images/loading.gif"></div>
    <div id="dailyEngagedUsers"><img src="css/images/loading.gif"></div>
    <div id="dailyEngagedUsers2"><img src="css/images/loading.gif"></div>
</div>
```

I want to export the divs that are shown to one PDF file. I never did something similar before and I prefer to use PHP if is possible for this task. Something like a button with "Download as PDF" is what I am looking for in the end. What is the best approach for my needs? I've tried with jsPDF library but I got into problems using it and I will prefer a back-end programming language like PHP.

Comment: Well there are FPDF www.fpdf.org or TCPDF www.tcpdf.org/‎ or PDFlib Lite http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdf.php, so give them a try.

Comment: Also tools like html2pdf and the like come in handy sometimes. And you have the option to use a "headless browser" and make a virtual screenshot which you print into a pdf file.

Comment: I would use tcpdf lib and create html with tables since that is the preffered way to render pdf exactly as you want it with this library and offcourse some inline styling

Comment: It seems that I generate canvas elements that are not supported in all of the libraries...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use php libraries tcpdf  or dompdf for your need. Both will work fine for your need. **TCPDF** is better than **dompdf** for using `DIV`

Comment: I've tried the HTML2PDF library and I receive an error like "The tag CANVAS does not yet exist", this probably because the canvas are not supported in this version right? Is there a library that support them?